# Conversion Char to double

Tags: java, char, double

How may I convert a numerical value in the form of a char to a double value?

I've tried just casting the char to a double but... it doesn't work like that I'm guessing as char such as '4' will convert to 52.0 in doubles.

So is there a way to convert a char with a value of say 
    char c = '4' 
to a double value of 4.0 where I can actually perform mathematical calculations on the value?

This is just a little program I created to show that casting a numeric char directly to a double won't work the way I was expecting.

```
public class conversion
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    char eight = '8';
    char four = '4';

    double d2 = (char)eight;
    double d1 = (char)four;

    System.out.println(d2);
    System.out.println(d1);

    double result = (d2 / d1);

    System.out.println(result);
}
}
```

outputs:

```
56.0
52.0
1.0769230769230769
```

Comment: Try casting to `int` first, then to `double`.

Comment: A `char` is just an integer which has a symbol representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
double d2 = (double) Character.digit(eight, 10);
double d1 = (double) Character.digit(four, 10);
```

Or:

```
double d2 = (double) (eight - '0');
double d1 = (double) (four - '0');
```

If you want to convert a whole string, use [`Double.parseDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29)

```
double d2 = Double.parseDouble("15.5");
```

Beware of a possible [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) is the string is an invalid floating point number

Answer (score 2):

You can subtract `'0'` then cast as a `double`:

```
char c = '8';

double d = (double) (c - '0');  // <--

System.out.println(d);
```

```
8.0
```

You can check that `c` is valid via `'0' <= c && c <= '9'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use :

```
double d2 = Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(eight));
double d1 = Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(four));
```

Comment: This is really overkill for something so simple.

Comment: @arshajii Consider that it will throw exception on invalid input, which OP might want.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It's trivial to check for invalid input beforehand (see my answer).

Comment: @arshajii At least if the OP has one day `String numb = "12.5";`, that might help.

Answer (score 1):

When you cast like that it returns the ASCII code of 4 or 8. The following code is what you want:

```
char myc='4';
double myd= Double.parseDouble(Character.toString(myc));
```

Answer (score 0):

The character `'0'` does not correspond to the integer `0`.  It corresponds to the ASCII key code for the `'0'` character.  Fortunately, the key codes for the characters `'0'` through `'9'` are sequential, so you can simply subtract `'0'` to convert a numeric character to the integer number it represents:

```
double d2 = (char)(eight - '0');
double d1 = (char)(four - '0');
```

Comment: so does this only work for characters '0' through '9'? is there a simple way to convert higher numeric values? *edit forget I ask that illogical question, completely forgot chars can only single digits

Comment: Higher base-10 numeric values cannot be represented by a single character.  There is no character `'15'`, for example.  If you want to convert a string of numbers, you can use a built-in function like `Integer.parseInt()` or do this conversion one character at a time, multiplying the intermediate result by `10` for each additional digit.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
char doubleChar = '8';
double doubleDouble = Double.parseDouble(Character.toString(doubleChar));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the char to a string and then to double like this:

```
double d2 = Double.parseDouble(Character.toString(eight));
double d1 = Double.parseDouble(Character.toString(four));
```