# How to get a float from a character

Tags: java

I have a char like

`'0'`

From which I need to get the `float` value

`0.0`

However, when I try casting the `char` to a `float` using `(float)'0'` I get `48.0` instead of `0.0`. The same thing happens when I attempt to use the `float.valueOf('0')` method.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion Char to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987628/conversion-char-to-double)

Comment: Try to convert '0' to int then you cast it to float

Comment: The other question is about double, but works the same for float.

Comment: Actually, every boxing type has a `valueOf(String)` method.

Answer (score 1):

By casting char to float you are getting char ascii value. Float parseFloat and valueOf methods can be used to value casting. You can read this page for detailed info from here: https://way2java.com/casting-operations/java-char-to-float If you convert char to string and try below you can get the desired result:

```
String a = "0";
float f = Float.valueOf(a);
System.out.println(f);
```

Comment: This yields the same result, as mentioned in my question

Comment: In your example your 0 is a ‘String’ not a ‘char’.

Comment: valueOf method expects string or float. Why are you giving char as a parameter to this method?

Comment: Question is clear you are trying to cast char to float and I explained in my answer why you cannot do that in your way.

Comment: I am aware that I cannot do it my way which is why I am asking how to do it, not why my way is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subtract the ASCII (unicode) value for '0' (which is why you get 48.0)...

```
public class CTF {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char c = '0';
        float f = (float) (c - '0');
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

It's a bit odd though because if you input a non-number such as 'G', you get 23.0. ' ' yields -16.0

Answer (score 0):

Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf('0'));

> > 0.0