# How to convert char x, which stores a numeric value, to double value without using second variable in Java?

Tags: java

I have tried:-

```
public class q1{ 
public void main(){ 
char x = '1' 
int z; 
double y; 
z = (int)x; 
y = (double)z; 
} 
}
```

Only problem is ASCII code of 1 (i.e. 49) is coming as the answer
I just want '1' to become 1.(no other variables allowed)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conversion Char to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19987628/conversion-char-to-double)

Answer (score 1):

Basically `(double) (c - 48)`.

Example:

```
private static char int2char(int x) {
    return (char) (x + 48);
}
private static int char2int(char x) {
    return ((int) x - 48);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    IntStream.range(0, 10)
            .forEach(i -> System.out.printf("#%d => %c => %f%n", i, int2char(i), (double) char2int(int2char(i))));

}
```

with output

```
#0 => 0 => 0,000000
#1 => 1 => 1,000000
#2 => 2 => 2,000000
#3 => 3 => 3,000000
#4 => 4 => 4,000000
#5 => 5 => 5,000000
#6 => 6 => 6,000000
#7 => 7 => 7,000000
#8 => 8 => 8,000000
#9 => 9 => 9,000000
```

Comment: You forget to mention that 48 is the ASCII code for '0', so your code comes down to: `(double) (c - '0')` or (in case subtracting of chars it not permitted): `(double)((int)c - (int)'0')`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Character.getNumericValue(char ch)`, like

```
int z = Character.getNumericValue(x);
```